# Rails redirect_to happening before page even shows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a checkout sequence in my app like this:

1. Cart - The user's tax is calculated and they hit a checkout button
2. `charges#address`  - There is a form to update the shipping address in the `user` table
3. `charges#shipping` - The user chooses a shipping method (which updates `order.total` in the database)
4. `charges#new` - Stripe actually makes a charge

My issue is that, for some reason, the `charges#shipping` (step 3 is skipped, it goes from 2 to 4) is being skipped over entirely.  The information for each step is below.

**Step 2 Information**

The form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@user, url: user_path(@user), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs text-left">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label :street_address_1 %>
        <%= f.text_field :street_address_1, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label :street_address_2 %>
        <%= f.text_field :street_address_2, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label :city %>
        <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control" %>
      </div><div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <%= f.label :state %>
        <%= f.text_field :state, class: "form-control" %>
      </div><div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <%= f.label :zip %>
        <%= f.text_field :zip, class: "form-control" %>
      </div><div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label :provence %>
        <%= f.text_field :provence, class: "form-control" %>
      </div><div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label :country %>
        <%= f.text_field :country, class: "form-control" %>
      </div><div class="form-group">
        <%= f.hidden_field :has_shipping, value: true %>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- form inputs -->
      <%= f.button :submit, "Calculate Shipping" %>
  <% end %>
```

The method in `users_controller` which should be sending it to the `charges#shipping` page, but it ends up on `charges#new`:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
    if @user.update(account_update_params)
      redirect_to charges_shipping_path
    else
      render :back
      flash[:notice] = "Something is amuck."
    end
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :phone, :admin, :stripe_customer_id, :street_address_1, :street_address_2, :city, :state, :zip, :provence, :country, :has_shipping)
  end
```

Here's what's happening in the server:

```
Started PUT "/users/1" for ::1 at 2017-05-16 10:04:10 -0700
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"R2ZDErL9UQ6nPNyYDI9FDeOp0x29t+/STWIkTKeShz2WWdO8kWu+z6V5NS/EKI6uiLcCAQBbwbsRMlhGs8v2VA==", "user"=>{"street_address_1"=>"10 Oak View Drive", "street_address_2"=>"Test", "city"=>"Aliso Viejo", "state"=>"CA", "zip"=>"92656", "provence"=>"", "country"=>"US", "has_shipping"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Calculate Shipping", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/charges/shipping
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/charges/shipping" for ::1 at 2017-05-16 10:04:10 -0700
Processing by ChargesController#shipping as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Order Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  OrderItem Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 5]]
  Product Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."active" = ? AND "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["active", "t"], ["id", 2]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."active" = ? AND "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["active", "t"], ["id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
156.95
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/charges/new
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."active" = ? AND "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["active", true], ["id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."active" = ? AND "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["active", true], ["id", 1]]
Completed 302 Found in 1965ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)


Started GET "/charges/new" for ::1 at 2017-05-16 10:04:12 -0700
Processing by ChargesController#new as HTML
  Order Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Rendered charges/_shipping.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered charges/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  OrderItem Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 5]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."active" = ? AND "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["active", "t"], ["id", 2]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."active" = ? AND "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["active", "t"], ["id", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_cart_text.html.erb (6.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 82ms (Views: 80.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Here's the form in **step 3** (the one being skipped, though all that really matters here is that it's a `form_for(@order)`:

```
  <h3>Shipping Rates</h3>
    <% shipping_choices = [] %>
    <% @ups_rates.each do |rate| %>
      <% choice = [] %>
      <% choice << number_to_currency(rate[1]/100) %>
      <% choice << number_to_currency(rate[1]/100).to_s + " - " + rate[0].to_s %>
      <% shipping_choices << choice %>
    <% end %>
  <%= simple_form_for order_path(@order) do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-inputs text-left">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :shipping, shipping_choices, :first, :last, item_wrapper_class: :block_radio_button_collection %>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- form inputs -->
    </div> <!-- choices row -->
    <div class="row">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Calculate Shipping" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

And here's the `order#update` method:

```
  def update
    @order = current_order
    if @order.update(order_params)
      redirect_to charges_address_path
    else
      render :back
      flash[:notice] = "Something is amuck."
    end
  end
```

This is a very strange problem for me.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**Additional Information**

```
As requested, here is my (unfortunately long) `charges#shipping` method:

def shipping
    @user = current_user
    @products = current_order.order_items.all
    @order = current_order
    if @order.update(order_params)
      new_total = @order.total + @order.shipping
      @order.update_attributes(total: new_total)
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    else
      render :back
      flash[:notice] = "Something is amuck."
    end

    @envelope_weight = 0
    @not_envelope = 0
    @products.each do |thing|
      if thing.product.envelope
        @envelope_weight += thing.product.weight
      else
        @not_envelope += 1
      end
    end

    if @not_envelope == 0
      # shipping for envelope
    else
      packages =  []
      @products.each do |thing|
        unless thing.product.envelope
          if thing.id == 1
            packages << ActiveShipping::Package.new( (thing.product.weight + @envelope_weight ) * 16,
            [thing.product.box_length, thing.product.box_width, thing.product.box_depth],
            units: :imperial)
          else
            packages << ActiveShipping::Package.new( thing.product.weight * 16,
            [thing.product.box_length, thing.product.box_width, thing.product.box_depth],
            units: :imperial)
          end # envelope weight if else
        end #unless
      end ## each do
    end # not envelope if/else

    origin = ActiveShipping::Location.new( country: 'US', state: 'CO', city: 'Sedalia', zip: '80135')

    if @user.country == 'US'
      destination = ActiveShipping::Location.new( country: @user.country, state: @user.state, city: @user.city, zip: @user.zip)
    else
      destination = ActiveShipping::Location.new( country: @user.country, province: @user.state, city: @user.city, postal_code: @user.zip)
    end # if/else for country

    ups = ActiveShipping::UPS.new(login: 'lizbayardelle', password: 'UPSpassw0rd', key: '3D287D7B39D0D398')
    ups_response = ups.find_rates(origin, destination, packages)
    @ups_rates = ups_response.rates.sort_by(&:price).collect {|rate| [rate.service_name, rate.price]}

    usps = ActiveShipping::USPS.new(login: '380LINCH6422')
    usps_response = usps.find_rates(origin, destination, packages)
    @usps_rates = usps_response.rates.sort_by(&:price).collect {|rate| [rate.service_name, rate.price]}
  end
```

Comment: Can you share the code for ChargesController#shipping where the unwanted redirect actually happened.

Comment: @rohan, yes that would be important...so added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you redirected from `UsersController#update` to `ChargesController#shipping`, it went into the shipping action where the condition for if `@order.update(order_params)` became true as order_params is nil here and hence it redirected to `ChargesController#new`

When you do a redirect_to in rails, it redirects as a GET request. When you submit a form, it will be POST/PUT by default(unless you change it).
You can even see in your logs, how all redirects are going in as GET.

It is not advisable to use same action for both. If you do want to use same action make sure you are adding a check for `request.method=='GET'` or `request.method=='POST'` in them.

From what I see in your shipping action code, it was written to handle form submits(POST) and not for handling GET requests via redirects.
So either handle it logically or seperate it into seperate actions, one to render the form and other to handle the form submit.

P.S. Also do not forget to add 'and return' after each redirect.

```
redirect_to charges_shipping_path and return
```

Comment: This is a lot of good information.  I copied the `@order = current_order` into a new `update_order` method in the charges controller and moved the if/else statement to it from the shipping method and it officially let me view the page!  I'll choose this answer because you definitely solved the problem at hand, but any help on how to structure the new `update_order` method to function would be greatly appreciated!